# Typescript Generic Function Interface in another interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic interface

```
export interface Method<T> {
    (answer: T): T;
}
```

I want to create an interface where I have fn function

```
interface Wrapper {
    fn: <T,>(a: T ) => T
}
```

but instead of manually writing the function type I want to use the interface

```
interface MethodWrapper {
   fn: Method
}
```

I want the `fn` to be generic at fn level not at the interface level. Is it possible?

[ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLITACwPYBMA8AKgHzIDeAUMtcgBRwgDOA7tAFzKHICUHhA3BQC+FCqEixEKAOpQ4AB3nRyVZDBAciAGmL0+3ZAF5ShYaPHR4SNBhy5ZCpVBXV1HdFjzCgA) link

Comment: Does that mean you do not want to pass a generic type into `MethodWrapper`?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to do; `interface  MethodWrapper<T> {fn: Method<T>}`

Comment: Alright. I think it's not possible to achieve your desired result then, but hopefully somebody else has another idea and can solve this. I for one think it is not possible.

Comment: Can't you define the function type like this? `type Method = <T>(answer: T) => boolean`. That's the kind of type that TS creates when you define a generic function.

Comment: TypeScript lacks the expressiveness to convert `Method<T>` into `Wrapper` programmatically. You'd need something like *generic values* as requested in [ms/TS#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) to do that.  But the type `<T,>(a: T)=>boolean` is unnecessarily generic anyway, it is equivalent to `(a: unknown)=>boolean` [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/mpnezw). Could you modify your example so that the generic is required (e.g., `<T,>(a: T) => T`) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3P0qW)?  Once you do that I could write up an answer explaining why this isn't possible.

Comment: @jcalz updated the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's type system lacks the expressiveness to programmatically transform `Method<T>` into `Wrapper`.  You'd need to move the scope of the generic type parameter `T` around in ways that can't be done.

If TypeScript had *generic values* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574), then you might be able to say something like:

```
// Invalid TypeScript, don't do this
interface Wrapper {
  fn: forall T. Method<T>;
}
```

or

```
// Invalid TypeScript, don't do this
interface Wrapper {
  fn: <T> Method<T>;
}
```

But it doesn't so we can't.

---

You can *almost* do it the other way around and define `Method<T>` in terms of `Wrapper`, using [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions).  I say "almost" because it requires that you drop down to the type level and acquire (or pretend to acquire) a value `wrapper` of type `Wrapper` before lifting back up to the type level.  Like this:

```
declare const wrapper: Wrapper; // pretend to have this

type Method<T> = typeof wrapper.fn<T> // instantiate fn with <T>
// type Method<T> = (a: T) => T
```

Depending on your use case that may or may not be helpful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLITACwPYBMA8AKgHzIDeAUMsgBRwgDOA7tAFzKECU7hA3BQF8KFUJFiIUAdShwADrOjkqyGCHZEANMmJ0enZAF5SfQcNHR4SNBhy5pchVCXVV7dFjz4AriADWIbCYQYlMKGB8EMGBsEGQAWy8wLzgAGxSATwBBBgZgAHMQOAAjFIgaAA83Gzx7eWgtdPZax31KanTDZHLeZAB6XuRoKGwoAEJlcs70nv7kbF84dNDZ83ErZsVKWZc1ZCJSd1t9-lmhYUK4iAZZCWQASUYwZ2RcCAQUuCgUBBiGJ6YZHUoE1AY5+NQwOkFNYPAQSJ1IQpsDBkACHNAAHSqfbKWaIlCHTzwgy0OB6QzGQRAA)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question fully, but guessing from your TS playground you need to pass the type of the generic:

```
interface MethodWrapper {
   fn: Method<T> // T should be the type you want fn to receive
}
```

Comment: Won't work, ts would just say `Cannot find name 'T'.(2304)`

Comment: Of course, you need to replace T with the actual type you want to use. Can you include an example of how you'd like to use such thing?

Comment: The whole question is can I do it dynamically, i.e the invoker decides what is the type of T